# How to embed path to the current path at anchor href?

Tags: html, href

For example, right now I'm at `http://example.com/practice`

If I have a link within the generated page: `<a href="5">Click here</a>`, I'm directed to `http://example.com/5`.

Now I know that this is the usual method of relative path. But what I actually need here is so that the link will take me to `http://example.com/practice/5` without I need to specify `practice` or `example.com` on that page. Preferred if not using any Javascript if possible, but if it is not possible, then I guess I'll have to use Javascript then.

I've already tried `<a href="./5">Click here</a>` and `<a href="./5/">Click here</a>` and they still work exactly like `"5"`.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Only "directories" are inherited in relative paths. So that if you want to use pure html, you have to make the current path like 'http://example.com/practice/' - otherwise just use window.location to build new path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something in your javascript where you grab the current location with window.location.href (there may be a better way depending if you're using any js frameworks). For example for this page, window.location.href returns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284340/how-to-embed-path-to-the-current-path-at-anchor-href

You could then do something like this

```
var baseUrl = window.location.href;
var aTag = document.querySelector(<selector for your anchor tag>);
aTag.setAttribute("href", baseUrl + "/" + <url we want to go to>);
```

So essentially we grab our current location, change the href of the tag we want to navigate to, then add whatever subroute we want to go to at the end. Kind of a weird way to do it, but like I said earlier, there may be an easier way if you're using react or angular or some other framework or library.

Comment: Alright then, looks like it's really impossible without the Javascript. Thank you for the explanation and Javascript code! :)